# Shell script loop with File extension is not working as expected

Tags: shell

I have a shell script which gets all the .zips file from the directory and does some processing. But when there is no file present in the directory the loop should not execute. But somehow the loop is still being executed.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FROM_XML_ZIPS=/Users/Docs_2020/ZIP/XML/*.zip

# files
echo "testing .zip files now"
for f in $FROM_XML_ZIPS;
do
  echo "validating $f"
done
```

Results in

```
testing .zip files now
validating /Users/Docs_2020/ZIP/XML/*.zip
```

Is there something i am missing ?

Comment: `*.zip` expands to all the names in the current directory that match the glob.  If there are none, it expands to the literal string `*.zip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you used **"globbing"** feature.

bash recognize glob patterns(*, ...etc) in unquoted string and then try to find matching files.

if no matching files, it just return same string

---

add `shopt` command above globbing line to return **null** when files not exist

```bash
shopt -s nullglob
/Users/Docs_2020/ZIP/XML/*.zip
```